# Reaching out DHCP relayed hosts

Tags: linux, networking, routing, dhcp, nat

I have one primary server (DHCP) and one secondary (DHCP-RELAY).

Majority of hosts are served from primary (wirelessly), however there are a few (wired ones) which get their IPs from secondary.

Secondary relays all `DHCP` traffic to primary, primary spawns `IP address`, sends it back to the secondary and then IP is fed up to the host. `isc-dhcp-[relay|server]`:

```
 __________                  ___________                  ___________
|   DHCP   |<----rel.req----| DHCP-RELAY|<=====ip.req====|    Host   |
|172.16.1.1|-{172.16.1.50}->|172.16.1.12|={172.16.1.50}=>|172.16.1.50|
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯                  ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯                  ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

---

*DHCP-SERVER*:

```
# ip route | grep 172
172.16.1.0/24 dev wlan5  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.1 
172.16.1.50 via 172.16.1.12 dev wlan5
```

*DHCP-RELAY*:

```
# ip addr | grep inet | grep 172
    inet 172.16.1.254/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet 172.16.1.12/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global wlan3

# ip route | grep 172
default via 172.16.1.1 dev wlan3  metric 300 
172.16.1.0/24 dev wlan3  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.12 
172.16.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.1.254 
172.16.1.50 via 172.16.1.254 dev eth0

# iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 1293 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 402 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 28 packets, 1568 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 28 packets, 1568 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    7   468 SNAT       all  --  *      eth0    172.16.1.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            to:172.16.1.254
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but to my knowledge with my current config it works in such or similar fashion:
*From DHCP-server (172.16.1.1<-->172.16.1.50)*

```
172.16.1.1---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.12
172.16.1.12---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.254
172.16.1.254---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.50
172.16.1.254<---icmp.pong---172.16.1.50
172.16.1.12<--icmp.pong----172.16.1.254
172.16.1.1<---icmp.pong---172.16.1.12
```

So I was expecting, that if I `ping` from the custom host behind the primary server:
*From Host (172.16.1.100<-->172.16.1.50)*

```
172.16.1.100---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.1
172.16.1.1---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.12
172.16.1.12---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.254
172.16.1.254---icmp.ping--->172.16.1.50
172.16.1.254<---icmp.pong---172.16.1.50
172.16.1.12<--icmp.pong----172.16.1.254
172.16.1.1<---icmp.pong---172.16.1.12
172.16.1.100<---icmp.pong---172.16.1.1
```

But instead I get `Destination Host Unreachable`...

I must add another `static route` on the host:

```
172.16.1.100:~# ip route add 172.16.1.50 via 172.16.1.12
```

Then all goes well. And that, dear gentlemen, is a lot of static routes!!

So what am I missing, is there a better approach to the problem?
I want that every host on the network could communicate with any other host on the same network, using as less as possible static routes.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you're confusing `DHCP` (which is to do with allocation of IP addresses and delivering network config information to clients) with routing of packets. It might be that the servers involved are performing both functions but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that all of your network interfaces appear to be on the same /24 subnet and so expect to be able to reach each other without going through a gateway. If you've got distinct sets of machines that need to go through a router to reach each other then they should be on different subnets.

Comment: You are missing one point - most of my machines operate `wireless`, therefore I have what I have. Main `dhcp` server serves them all, including the secondary, which gives ip addresses to the wired hosts. Ultimately secondary becomes a firewall and I have to route my packets, otherwise hosts behind secondary can see main server, but server can't see the host. Secondary is a gateway for the wired hosts to the primary `dhcp` server which is also internet gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> So what am I missing, is there a better approach to the problem? I
>   want that every host on the network could communicate with any other
>   host on the same network, using as less as possible static routes.

You can use a VLAN and bridge your wireless and ethernet segments together. With this configuration you will create a single broadcast domain, no static routes are required and only one DHCP server is needed.

There are two options on the bridging side:

1. Set the Access Points in bridge mode and connect their ethernet to a switch port on your VLAN
2. Let all Access Points reach the DHCP server and add a bridge interface there

I personally would go for the first option since it is more scalable.

**Option #1 (Architecture)**

```
 ______________                ___________                  ___________
|Wireless      |<==Ethernet===|Switch 1  |<====Ethernet====|Switch 2   |
|Access Point 1|=============>|on VLAN A |================>|on VLAN A  |     
 ---------------               -----------                  -----------
                                      |                             |
                                   Ethernet                    Ethernet
                                      |                             |
                                  __________                    _________
                                 | DHCP     |                  |  Wired  |
                                 | Server   |                  |  Hosts  |
                                  ----------                    ---------
                                Serves IPs for
                                subnet {172.16/16}
```

The fact that all hosts and Access Points are connected to the same VLAN allows you to reach them using a single DHCP server without any specific routing, it will all work at Level 2 of the network stack.

**Option #2 (Architecture)**

```
 ______________              _________________                __________
|Wireless      |<==Ethernet==|eth0|DHCP  |eth1|<==Ethernet===|Switch    |          
|Access Point 1|============>|    |Server|    |=============>|          |  
---------------              |     --------   |               ----------           
                             |    bridge0     |                    |
                              ----------------                   Ethernet
                              Only bridge0 interface               |
                              is given an IP address          __________
                              and DHCP servers is             |  Wired  |
                              configured to serve IPs         |  Hosts  |
                              on subnet {172.16/16}           -----------
                              only on bridge0 interface
```

`bridge0` is a virtual interface that bridges `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces on the DCHP server (here I am assuming a linux box but is the same concept on other OSes). `eth0` and `eth1` mustn't have any IP on their own, only `bridge0` should since is the only interface that will be *visible*(1) from an external point of view. Again, no static routing will be necessary.

*(1) I apologize for the non-technical language but I think that a too technical explanation would clutter the answer and is not strictly necessary in order to show the concept.*

Comment: I have not considered VLANs because this would require extra config on each machine. For routing/switching I have a regular headless linux box.. These are mostly Debian based. Could you please recommend some package for VLANs? As debian's network/interfaces seem to have just ethX.Y (Y for vlan ID) syntax, and are quite limited.

Comment: I added the VLAN terminology to be as broad as possible, however, the setup exposed can be used without any VLAN configuration if you can have dedicated switches for this subnet. In regards to any vlan package, I cannot offer you much advice since I use the way defined in debian [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Bridges_and_VLANs), which, as you said, it defines network interfaces as ethX.Y (Y for vlan ID). I am not aware of any specific debian package to help on VLAN configuration.